# Resource with cache headers still going out

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, browser-cache

On a call I want to get cached forever, I put these headers (from the response i see):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By    Express
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control   public, max-age=31536000
Expires Wed, 14 May 2014 21:09:45 GMT
Last-Modified   Tue, 14 May 2013 21:09:45 GMT
Date    Tue, 14 May 2013 21:09:45 GMT
Connection  keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
```

And yet, when I reload the page, I can see these requests still going out to the network.
What headers should I have put to prevent the calls from going out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you reload a page with the "Reload" or "Refresh" feature of a browser, it does re-request all resources (even if they are cached).

Do you see the same requests going out if you simply browse to the page again instead of reload it?  e.g. Open a new tab and enter the URL of the page in question there, you should see that the browser is not making the request.  If it is still making the request then you can look at the browser's settings to ensure it is not configured to behave this way.

Your cache-control header looks good, and a well behaved browser shouldn't request the resource more than once unless its cache was cleared or the max age has been exceeded.

Comment: This is actually in an app (Phonegap), so when I re-open the app I see (via a proxy I put in the middle) that these requests do go out.